# Sonatype Nexus 3 504 Gateway Timeout when pushing to hosted Docker repository

Tags: timeout, nexus, sonatype, http-status-code-504

I am getting 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT when pushing to a hosted Docker repo on Sonatype Nexus 3. I'm trying to push a multi-GB layer:

```
    451c9f0946ad: Image already exists
    97444a62d0da: Image already exists
    3acdb070c7f5: Image already exists
    78362681bd49: Image already exists
    5890a244c36a: Pushing [==================================================>] 2.403 GB
    Received unexpected HTTP status: 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT
```

It seems to error after about 4 to 4.5 minutes. I don't see a way to adjust the timeout on the Nexus side. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get error 504 from a reverse proxy running in front of Nexus, not from Nexus itself.  Do you have nginx or Apache or similar running in front of the server?  If so check the configuration there.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I looked at the AWS ELB config more closely which I'm using in front of Nexus. I found an "Idle Timeout" setting that defaults to 60 seconds and set it much higher (300 seconds). This seemed to fix things. Thanks again!

Comment: Also have this problem running with AWS ALB. Increasing the idle timeout does not seem to help. Did you find another solution?